# Create struct with empty variables

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a `struct` with empty variables in it. Here's how I want it to be:

```
var myStruct = {
    value1,
    value2
}
```

Then I would use it like this

```
var myValue = myStruct.value1;

if (myValue === myStruct.value1) {
    //Do some code
} else {
    //Do something else
}
```

Is there a way of doing that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use `null` or `undefined` values to do it:

```
var myStruct = { value1: null, value2: null }
```

or:

```
var myStruct = { value1: undefined, value2: undefined }
```

The reason why you may prefer `undefined` over `null`, is that `null === undefined` returns `false`, so you can differentiate between the structs that were never initialized, and those which just hold a null value, if that's important for your app.

Comment: Gotcha! I like your answer! Gonna accept it after the timer. :) Why didn't anyone up-vote my question?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myStruct = {
    value1: null,
    value2: null
}
```

You just have to set them to null in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, in fact in a very similar syntax:

```
var myStruct = {
    value1: null,
    value2: null
}
```

Depending on how you define *empty*, you can use empty-strings `""` if that's what you are looking for.